# Speed up many UNIX read/write calls in C

Tags: c, unix, io

I'm writing a program (fair warning, it's a homework problem) that will be sorting 50 million floats it receives as an input file and outputting them to another file. I am using the UNIX standard read() and write() calls to read in the input and write them to the file, however it seems to be running quite slowly because of how many of these calls there are.

Here is the relevant code for reading:

```
floats* input = make_floats(0); // input floats

int ifd = open(iname, O_RDONLY, 0644);

long count; // temp to get count

read(ifd, &count, sizeof(long)); // read in count

// read in numbers from input
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    float num;

    read(ifd, &num, sizeof(float));

    floats_push(input, num);
}
```

it reads in the numbers one at a time into a float vector (that is the floats*).

Here is the writing:

```
floats* xs = make_floats(0);
int ofd = open(args->output, O_WRONLY, 0644);
int xs_counter = 0;

// write the local array to file
for (int i = start; i < end; ++i) {
    write(ofd, &(xs->data[xs_counter]), sizeof(float));
    ++xs_counter;
}
```

start and end are the essentially how much I'm writing. I'm wondering if I can essentially make these into a single mass read and write call, but I'm a little lost as to how (the code works fine btw it's just slow)

Thanks

Comment: You could use `fread` / `fwrite` instead.

Comment: wish I could, the assignment specifies read/write

Comment: Can you read bunch at once with `read` into an array?

Comment: How fast is the read if you don't do floats_push?

Comment: If I don't push it only speeds up minimally (tenths of a second), and yeah it seems like I could read all into an array, would I just pass in the pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing all those read calls with a single read:

```
float *numbers = malloc(sizeof(float) * count);
read(ifd, numbers, sizeof(float) * count);
```

Comment: had to modify it a bit but this worked great for reading, thanks

Comment: @AJwr great! Just make sure to call `free(numbers);` if you used dynamic memory after you are done accessing the values to clean up the heap.

Comment: And if `count` is large, that `read()` call will almost certainly return less than the requested number of bytes.  [`read()` returns a value for a reason](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html): "The `read()` function **shall *attempt* to read `nbyte` bytes** from the file associated with the open file descriptor... Upon successful completion, these functions shall return a non-negative integer indicating the number of bytes actually read."